# Synchronous video playback on multiple Android devices

Tags: android, library, automation, video-player

I have multiple Android-based projectors (Xiaomi 4k) and want them to start playback of a movie file at the same time. It's not the same file on each device, so casting wouldn't work. What I need is to somehow be able to send the "play" command to all of the devices simultaneously. I also need to be able to schedule these "play" commands, so they are triggered automatically during the day.

Maybe there are some open-source players/libraries that I can start with to build such an app?

Comment: (Accidentally) migrated from Android.SE: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/253129/44325